# undefined method `seasons' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a problem. Can anybody tell me why?

When I go to this link - **localhost:3000/serial-name**, it return -

**NoMethodError in SerialsController#show**

**undefined method `seasons' for nil:NilClass**

My code

**serial.rb**

```
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

def to_param
  name.parameterize
end

has_many :seasons
```

**season.rb**

```
validates :season_number, presence: true, uniqueness: true, 
                          :numericality => { greater_than_or_equal_to: 1 }

belongs_to :serial
```

**serials_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @serials = Serial.all
end

def show
  @serial = Serial.find_by_name(params[:id])
  @seasons = @serial.seasons
end
```

**serials_controller.rb**

```
get '/:name', to: 'serials#show', as: :serial
root 'serials#index'
```

Comment: `Serial.find_by_name(params[:id])` returns `nil`, you probably want to use `Serial.find_by_name!(params[:id])` (with exclamation mark) instead. You can also use `Serial.find_by(name: params[:id])`. Both of these versions will raise an exception, instead of returning `nil`, if there is no record with given name.

Comment: Confirm that you are getting the name in `params[:id]`. Have you tried `Serial.find_by_name(params[:name])`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def show
  @serial = Serial.find_by!(name: params[:id])
  @seasons = @serial.seasons
end
```

`find_by!` will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception  if the record cannot be found. This will display the 404 error page.

But when defining vanity URLs its a good idea to allow both the "pretty" param and the id.

```
class Serial
  def self.find(id)
    where(id: id).or.where(name: id).first!
  end
end
```

---

```
def show
  @serial = Serial.find(id)
  @seasons = @serial.seasons
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
@serial = Serial.find_by_name(params[:id])
```

You are looking for the name in `params[:id]`, but `id` is not in `params` hash since you defined it to be `name` in your routes:

```
get '/:name', to: 'serials#show', as: :serial
```

So use `params[:name]` instead:

```
@serial = Serial.find_by_name(params[:name])
```

Comment: i can understand that) it really works. but i don't want "id" in url, i want beauty url with serial name. can you offer me some solution for this?